# Aggregating with CASE logic in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
  Client ID Value
  1       1   10
  1       2   20
  2       1   12
  2       2   15
  2       1   34
```

Desirable result is to get the aggragation of Value column(sum) grouping by Client for each ID in distinct column:

```
Client SUM_VALUE_1 SUM_VALUE_2
  1       10          20
  2       46          15
```

Trying to do that way:

```
Select Client, 
sum (Case When ID='1' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) as SUM_VALUE_1,
sum (Case When ID='2' THEN Value ELSE NULL END) as SUM_VALUE_2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Client
```

Is it right approach or it should be changed somehow?

Comment: What makes you think that it's not the right approach?

Comment: Your approach is fine; the `ELSE NULL` is redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want group the result by Client and ID you can do this:

```
  Select Client, ID, sum (value) as value
  FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY Client, ID
```

But if you want group by Client:

```
Select Client,sum(value) from (
  Select Client, ID, sum (value) as value
  FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY Client, ID)
GROUP BY Client;
```

or

```
Select Client,sum(value)
from TABLE
GROUP BY Client;
```

Comment: This doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: Return the result in distinct column for this case is ok , but if you have N number of ID in this table using your approach is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would say avoid null and use 0 instead

```
Select Client, 
sum (Case When ID='1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as SUM_VALUE_1,
sum (Case When ID='2' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) as SUM_VALUE_2
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Client
```